# .exe file execution from within

Tags: batch-file, exe, iexpress

If I make a file `foo.exe`, and it contains the files `bar.bat`, `baz.bat`, and `qux.bat`, can I call `baz.bat` from within `bar.bat`? I mean, if `bar.bat` is the file that is executed upon execution of `foo.exe`?

Comment: How, exactly, does `foo.exe` contain these files?

Comment: Well, I use iexpress to compress them into `foo.exe`.

Comment: I'd expect IExpress to first extract all contained files, and then run your `bar.bat` in the target directory. I have no experience with IExpress itself, but have you just tried it?

Comment: I don't have too much experience with how it works, but I do use it often, as it is a very handy tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done something similar using winrar (instead of iexpress) self extracting archive.

The mechanism is like below:

1. First it will extract everything to specified folder (or in temporary folder %TEMP%/random_name)
2. Then it will call initial executable/script or "script to run after extraction". In your case, it's bar.bat.
3. That executable script can in turn call any other script/executable. (baz.bat in your example)

To be sure, change the file bar.bat to contain below script:

```
@echo off
cd
explorer .
pause
```

This will print the directory name, where it has extracted & open the directory with explorer.exe. Then you can verify that your baz.bat is in same directory. Give relative path, if required.